# Ruby's best way to process thousand async requests?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, eventmachine, celluloid

The task is to process quote ticks almost realtime ( 1 second delay ).

At the moment I need to process about hundred quotes but it might increase to thousands. I'm looking at the `EM` currently to run ten threads each of which will run ten async requests and put data into some PubSub for later processing.

Also I'm testing `Celluloid-IO` with `HTTP` gem.

Am I on the right way? Tried to check GitHub for smth that I'm trying to implement but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the large amount of parallel requests sometimes its recommended to use [Fibers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fiber.html) instead of Threads as they are faster to fire and lighter in memory usage.

The most popular solution is [**EM-synchrony**](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) and you can use **EM::Synchrony::Iterator** for job scheduling and balancing.

Be aware that you should use according **EM**-libraries like "*em-synchrony/em-http*" for compatibility with **EM-synchrony**.

You can check [this](http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/) blogpost for more insights.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post and EM-synchrony, it would help me a lot.

Comment: My suggestion is stay away from EM if you can help it, the gem is no longer actively maintained and if you encounter any issue down the line somewhere far in the future which needs fixing in the gem, then you'll be on your own